# padding-top is not calculated against the width

Tags: css

according to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) I always used `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` to maintan the aspect ratio of a div. Today I faced simple structure which is not rendered with aspect of 5/2 (w/h). For `padding-top:40%` I expect a horizontal rectangle as the `padding-top` is calculated against the width. Why this is vertical? (It seems that the height is calculated against the parent width)

```css
#aspect52 {
    width:30%;
    padding-top:40%;
    background:#ff0000;
    position:absolute;
}

#parent{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="aspect52"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are limiting the width to 30%, when it should be 100% for your ratio. Put 30% on the parent not the child... see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/um0hqw35/)

Comment: The padding as percentage (%) will take the parent's width, not the parent's height. In any case, for me, I'd avoid percentage in padding as much as possible and take any other solution/workaround because I know I'll definitely end-up with cross-browser issues!